# Twitter Automation - Puppeteer - How can I optimize this loop to check three conditions at each iteration efficiently?

Tags: javascript, loops, web-scraping, dom, puppeteer

#### I'm trying to grab the Tweets using puppeteer and snscrape.

**How I want this to function:**

First, I grab the tweet URLs and username using the snscrape and store them in a JSON file as an array like this

```
[["https://twitter.com/NikkiSiapno/status/1595712124222857217", "NikkiSiapno"],  ["https://twitter.com/NikkiSiapno/status/1559472755443220481", "NikkiSiapno"]]
```

After this, I want to iterate through each URL one by one using Puppeteer, extract the text content of each tweet, and print them sequentially to the console while following these conditions:

- Check the heading title to determine whether it's a Tweet or a Thread. If it's a Tweet, extract only the first tweet.
- If it's a Thread, check if the user handle of the first n tweets matches with the user handle stored in the tweets.json file. If it matches, extract their text content.
- In a Thread, it shouldn't capture the replies of other users but only the tweets of the author. For that, it should evaluate the first 30 tweets in a thread (as the author's tweets are at the top), compare their user handle with the one stored in the JSON file, and extract the Text content if they match.

Problems:

- I can't figure out how to extract the user handle of each tweet and at the same time compare that with user handle in the authorName variable in each iteration.
- I'm unsure how to properly control the scroll to avoid skipping some tweets in a thread.

*Any help would be appreciated. Additionally, how can we optimize this code?*

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const tweetUrls = require("./tweets.json");
    for (let i = 0; i < tweetUrls.length; i++) {
        const tweetUrl = tweetUrls[i][0];
        const authorName = tweetUrls[i][1];
        await page.goto(tweetUrl, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

        // Wait for the tweets to load
        await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="tweet"]');
        // Wait for the sheetDialog element and close it.
        await page.waitForSelector('div[data-testid="sheetDialog"]');
        await page.click('div[data-testid="app-bar-close"]');

        // extract the heading title
        const tweetHeading = await page.$('h2[role="heading"]');
        const tweetHeadingText = await page.evaluate(
            (el) => el.querySelector("span").textContent,
            tweetHeading
        );

        // if the heading title is "Thread" execute this:
        if (tweetHeadingText === "Thread") {
            // extract the user handle
            const Handle = await page.$('div[data-testid="User-Names"]');
            const userHandle = await page.evaluate((el) => el.querySelector("a > div > span").textContent.substring(1), Handle
            );

            const tweetTextSet = new Set();

            let tweetCount = 0;

            // For the first n tweets, while the userHandle === authorName grab their text content.

            while (tweetCount < 30 && userHandle === authorName) {
                const tweetEls = await page.$$('[data-testid="tweetText"]');
                for (const tweetEl of tweetEls) {
                    const tweetText = await page.evaluate(
                        (el) => el.textContent.trim(), tweetEl
                    );
                    if (!tweetTextSet.has(tweetText)) {
                        console.log(tweetText);
                        tweetTextSet.add(tweetText);
                        tweetCount++;
                        if (tweetCount >= 40) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                await page.evaluate(() => {
                    window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
                });
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
            }
            // if the heading title is "Tweet" then only get the first tweet:
        } else if (tweetHeadingText === "Tweet") {
            const tweetEls = await page.$$('[data-testid="tweetText"]');
            const firstTweetEl = tweetEls[0];
            const firstTweetText = await page.evaluate(
                (el) => el.textContent.trim(),
                firstTweetEl
            );
            console.log(firstTweetText);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Seems like a repost of [this deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75564301/how-to-select-elements-with-puppeteer?noredirect=1#comment133338696_75564301). Please edit your existing one instead of reposting. Thanks.

Comment: No, this is different from the previous question. Please read both questions in detail.

Comment: OK, well, there's certainly a good deal of overlap. Can you narrow this down to one question rather than 3? Thanks.

Comment: But they are 2 separate questions. However, I have managed the Ist question, If you know the answer to 2nd question, please go ahead. Third one is optional.